# Impress.js Cube - change the direction of transition

Tags: css, impress.js

I made a cube in impress.js as my first practice project and its working fine except the transition from face 3 to 4.
Faces 1,2,3,4 are all parallel to Z-axis and placed in anticlockwise direction when viewed from top. Transition from 1 -> 2, 2 -> 3 (anticlockwise, from top) is ok but transition from 3->4 is clockwise,  ie it moves back to 2 then 1 then 4. Any way to change it so that it moves from 3 -> 4 directly?

Here's my code:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Cube using Impress.js</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body class="impress-not-supported">

    <div class="fallback-message">
            <!-- Message here -->
    </div>

    <div id="impress">

        <div id="face-1" class="step" data-z="350">
            This is face 1
        </div>

        <div id="face-2" class="step" data-x="350" data-rotate-y="90">
            This is face 2
        </div>

        <div id="face-3" class="step"data-z="-350" data-rotate-y="180">
            This is face 3
        </div>

        <div id="face-4" class="step" data-x="-350" data-rotate-y="-90">
            This is face 4
        </div>

        <div id="face-5" class="step" data-y="-350" data-rotate-x="90">
            This is face 5
        </div>

        <div id="face-6" class="step" data-y="350" data-rotate-x="-90">
            This is face 6
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="impress.js"></script>
    <script>impress().init();</script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

body {
    font: normal 70px/70px sans-serif;
    background: -webkit-radial-gradient(rgb(240, 240, 240), rgb(190, 190, 190));
}

b, strong { font-weight: bold }
i, em { font-style: italic }

.fallback-message {
    font-family: sans-serif;
    line-height: 1.3;

    width: 780px;
    padding: 10px 10px 0;
    margin: 20px auto;

    border: 1px solid #E4C652;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #EEDC94;
}

.fallback-message p {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

.impress-supported .fallback-message {
    display: none;
}

.step {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
    width: 700px;
    height: 700px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 25px;
    opacity: .3;
}

.step.active{ opacity: 1; }
```

Comment: No answers here too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11298185/how-to-get-a-full-seemless-rotation-with-impress-js

Comment: Have you tried using `data-rotate-y="270"` on face 4?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each step should be as close to the next step as possible. Instead of going from 180 to -90, go to 270 (even though that's the same).

This code should do what you want:

```
<div id="impress">

    <div id="face-1" class="step" data-z="350">
        This is face 1
    </div>

    <div id="face-2" class="step" data-x="350" data-rotate-y="90">
        This is face 2
    </div>

    <div id="face-3" class="step"data-z="-350" data-rotate-y="180">
        This is face 3
    </div>

    <div id="face-4" class="step" data-x="-350" data-rotate-y="270">
        This is face 4
    </div>

    <div id="face-5" class="step" data-y="-350" data-rotate-x="90" data-rotate-y="360">
        This is face 5
    </div>

    <div id="face-6" class="step" data-y="350" data-rotate-x="270" data-rotate-y="360">
        This is face 6
    </div>

</div>
```